# jQuery - Loading a div with large dataset in sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery to load a `<div>` element with a large data set.

Basic architecture is, Node.js using web sockets sends some data to the front end in the form of JSON. I want to display those details inside the `<div>` element.

```
$("#myDiv ul").append("<li>my test1</li>");
```

I call the above code inside a for loop based on the array length and vary the printed message:

```
data.forEach(function(e,i){
    $("#myDiv ul").append("<li>" + e.msg + "</li>");
})
```

**CSS:**

```
#myDiv {
display:block;
width:20%;
height:60%;
overflow:hidden
}
```

The problem is, the code works, the new `<li>` is getting added to the last. But the div is not showing the latest content. It is showing only the old content.

I want to create an interface similar to chat, where, when a new message is added, the old content, gets scrolled up and the new content is shown to the user.

The older `<div>` should keep on scrolling up and disappear after 1000 messages. How to achieve this in javascript?

Comment: You can use prepend instead of append
 $("#myDiv ul").prepend("<li>" + e.msg + "</li>");

Comment: If I've understood the question properly, you probably want this: https://github.com/litera/jquery-scrollintoview

Comment: I want something similar to chat application. but instead of user typing, i will be dynamically update the content from the database.

Comment: I want to create a effect similar to , there is a div, i always add some message at the bottom. All the div's on the top should move up. it is like, array push and pop. Once a limit is reached, the div should remove the top div and replace it with the next successor.